# How do I increase the rate limit for an Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, rate-limiting

I have this script for shortening URLs using the goo.gl shortener:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu("Shorten")
    .addItem("Go !!","rangeShort")
    .addToUi()  
}

function rangeShort() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(), data = range.getValues();
  var output = [];
  for(var i = 0, iLen = data.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    var url = UrlShortener.Url.insert({longUrl: data[i][0]});
    output.push([url.id]);
  }
  range.offset(0,1).setValues(output);
}
```

I have about 400 URLs to shorten, how do I get rid of the 'rate limit' please?

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the rate is probably not possible.  But perhaps staying within the rate might be acceptible.

```
function rangeShort() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(), data = range.getValues();
  var output = [];
  for(var i = 0, iLen = data.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    var url = UrlShortener.Url.insert({longUrl: data[i][0]});
    output.push([url.id]);
    Utilities.sleep(100);
  }
  range.offset(0,1).setValues(output);
}
```

[Reference Link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas)